# Why is Ruby erroring with ArgumentError (unknown keyword: api_key)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Just upgraded to:

```
ruby '2.4.2'
gem 'rails', '5.0'
```

Trying to test app and getting the following:

```
ArgumentError (unknown keyword: api_key):

app/models/user.rb:225:in `new'
app/models/user.rb:225:in `send_approval_code'
app/models/user.rb:292:in `create_new'
app/controllers/ms_controller.rb:249:in `create_dude'


def create_dude
attributes = {}
if params[:email].blank?
  render :js => "error('email2', 'required');"
  return
elsif params[:phone].blank?
  render :js => "error('phone2', 'required');"
  return
elsif User.where(:email => params[:email]).count > 0
  render :js => "error('email2', 'already exists');"
  return
elsif !params[:password].blank?
  if params[:password].length < 6
    render :js => "error('password2', 'must be at least 6 characters');"
    return
  elsif params[:password_confirmation].blank?
    render :js => "error('password_confirmation2', 'required');"
    return
  elsif params[:password] != params[:password_confirmation]
    render :js => "error('password_confirmation2', 'does not match');"
    return
  else
    attributes[:password] = params[:password]
  end
end
attributes[:email] = params[:email] if params[:email]
attributes[:password] = params[:password] if params[:password]
attributes[:password_confirmation] = params[:password] if params[:password]
attributes[:first_name] = params[:first_name] if params[:first_name]
attributes[:last_name] = params[:last_name] if params[:last_name]
attributes[:last_4_soc] = params[:last_4_soc] if params[:last_4_soc]
attributes[:drivers_license] = params[:drivers_license] if params[:drivers_license]
attributes[:phone] = params[:phone] if params[:phone]
attributes[:type] = User::PLOTTER
attributes[:emrt_id] = @emrt.id.to_s
attributes[:approved] = true
attributes[:verified_phone_number] = false
if @ems.type == Nms::MURSE
  attributes[:stand_alone_type] = params[:type]
end
r = User.create_new(attributes)
if r[:status] == 'OK'
  if @ems.type == Nms::MURSE
    u = User.where(:email => params[:email]).first
    u.create_stand_alone_amb(params[:plate_number]) if u
    u.stand_alone_amb.update_attributes(:icon_color => params[:color])
  end
  render :js => "location.reload();"
else
  render :js => "error('email2', 'error. please try again');"
end
```

end

The only reference to api_key I see is in SendGrid method.

```
client = SendGrid::Client.new(api_key: SENDGRID_PROD_KEY)
```

UPDATE:

I commented out the SendGrid code to see what would happen. Now getting

```
    ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)):

    app/models/user.rb:228:in `new'
    app/models/user.rb:228:in `send_approval_code'
    app/models/user.rb:292:in `create_new'
    app/controllers/ms_controller.rb:249:in `create_dude'
```

Comment: What did you upgrade from ? Also maybe, if your Sendgrid gem was not versioned and been upgraded to match Rails app, some changes have been made and this key deprecated ...

Comment: Ruby 2.3 and Rails 4.2.11

Comment: Are you sure Sendrig has not been updated from 2.x.x to 3.x.x It seems the syntax has changed to `SendGrid:: API` (really just a guess as I don't use Sendgrid)

Comment: Using sendgrid-ruby (5.3.0)